# Ironpython call numpy problem

Tags: python, ironpython, numpy

Ironpython 2.6,
python 2.6.5,
numpy,
SciPy

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'D:\Python26\dll')
sys.path.append(r'D:\Python26\Lib')
sys.path.append(r'D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages')

» import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 132, in 
  File "D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in 
  File "D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in 
  File "D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in 
  File "D:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in 
ImportError: No module named multiarray
```

What's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe you'll need IronClad.
http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/

Comment: I known this, but it also have some error:
http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/issues/detail?id=26

Comment: Did you run ironclad with -X:Frames?

Comment: @jcao219:If I use C# call ironpython, how can I use -X:Frames?

Comment: From looking at the IronPython source, it looks like you'll need to set LanguageSetup.Options["Frames"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True when you're setting up hosting.

Comment: @Giles Thomas :
Thanks a lot, that's OK!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it looks like [Giles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069820/ironpython-call-numpy-problem#comment3161202_3069820) did the trick:

> From looking at the IronPython source, it looks like you'll need to set LanguageSetup.Options["Frames"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True when you're setting up hosting.